# What are some examples of imagemagick commands where option can be provided between magick and input filename

Tags: imagemagick

For e.g.

`magick -density 100 apple.jpg -resize 100x100 apple-edited.jpg`

Density here is the option which has to be provided prior to input file name.
Can someone please explain when is such prior options are needed. And also provide me few more examples.

PS: I tried looking for the options but not sure if there is an specific term for such options which will help limit the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ImageMagick** is, exclusively, a *raster* image processor, which means that it processes bitmap images made up of *pixels* laid out on a rectangular grid (or *raster*), rather than a *vector*  image processor like **Adobe Illustrator** or **Inkscape** which deal with shapes, lines, rectangles and bezier curves described by their vertices or inflection points - not pixels.

When you load a vector image (e.g. an SVG image, or a PDF) into **ImageMagick**, the very first thing it does is rasterise your image onto a rectangular grid before it can work with the pixels. So, if your image is an SVG or a PDF, you need to set the density, or number of lines in the grid **before** you load the image.

I don't know of a reason to do that for a JPEG, like your example. I can't think of any other settings you absolutely need to make prior to loading an image.

Comment: If you have a CMYKA PDF, Ghostscript which imagemagick uses cannot handle that. So you must convert to RGB using -colorspace sRGB before reading the PDF file. With density, you should specify the -units also, though often that is assumed to be pixelsperinch.